# Rake aborted! Mysql2::Error: Access denied for 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to run rake db:migrate

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set up the database for a rails app. But when I run "rake db:migrate" from the terminal I encounter the following error: "Mysql2::Error: Access denied for 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)".

Many other people have reported similar permission errors, but none of their situations seem to describe mine. Here are some details.

My database.yml contains:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: [directory name]_development
  pool: 5
  username: [my username]
  password: [my user password on mysql]
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```

My Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.2'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.0'
end
group :test do
    gem 'faker'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'launchy'
    gem 'database_cleaner'
end
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap'
gem 'pg'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'better_errors'
```

I have run "gem clean", "bundle update", and "bundle install" from the terminal.

I have created the development database by signing in to the mysql monitor using "mysql -u root -p", running "create [name]_development;", and then granting permissions on that database using "grant all privileges on `[name]_development`.* to '[user name]'@’localhost’' with grant option;". I have checked and confirmed that both that my user name and database exists. I have confirmed that user@localhost has all permissions on my database.

I am calling rake from the directory of my rails app.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Created database using rake db:create?

Comment: run in mysql `Flush privileges` to make sure the user is updated.

Comment: rake db:create did it. Thank you!